# Provide deploy access to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have created an Elastic Beanstalk Node.js instance to host a simple application for demo purposes.

What I would like to do is provide access to another developer to deploy to this instance. They would like to use SFTP to access and upload builds. I believe that creating and sending them an IAM policy would be the route to go, but I don't know what policy they would need and what level of access. How should I set this up so they can only upload new files and code?

Answer (score 0):

The two permissions that you would have to start looking into are [CreateApplicationVersion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateApplicationVersion.html) and [UpdateEnvironment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_UpdateEnvironment.html). However any IAM permissions would require your developer to have AWS credentials, either from his/hers account or yours.

I think it would be easier and more straight forward to create simple [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/continuous-deployment-pipeline/) with Elastic Beanstalk action provider. So your developer would upload new code to some repository, S3, github, gitlab, CodeCommit, and the upload process would trigger it automated deployment in Elastic Beanstalk.